# Filter URL of img tags with HTMLpurifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm using htmlPurifier to filter user generated html. I want to filter all image URLs using a specific rule set while allowing more general hyperlinks.

How can I set up an URL filter that is only applied to img.src attributes but not to a.href attributes?

I guess, I need to set up a URI filter as described in http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-uri-filter.html. But I need to somehow restrict it to img.src attributes.

If I write a filter like this, is there a way to determine whether I'm currently operating on an img.src attribute or not?

```php
class HTMLPurifier_URIFilter_NameOfFilter extends HTMLPurifier_URIFilter
{
    public $name = 'NameOfFilter';
    public function prepare($config) {}
    public function filter(&$uri, $config, $context) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution:
The $context object contains information about the tag that is currently being processed. Thus, one can use:

```php
class HTMLPurifier_URIFilter_MyImages extends HTMLPurifier_URIFilter {
    public $name = 'MyImages';
    public $post = true;
    public function prepare($config) {}
    public function filter(&$uri, $config, $context) {
        if ($context->get('CurrentToken')->name == 'img') {
            // do something with the image url here
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```